# ReactJS: Properly handling user logged in data?

Tags: reactjs

So, currently, we send an API call to get user authentication data. User ID, Client ID, etc...

Then we pass this data to redux and load the user data into React Router through `connect()` and `mapStateToProps`...

Then each route gets this user data and passes it to the rendered component through props...

Then, in a lot of our components, we make more API calls using the user data.

However, most of the time, this data shows as an empty object `{}`

Is it best to pass this data down to components through React Router, or should we be getting the data from redux and mapStateToProps on each component that needs the user data?

Comment: I would use mapStateToProps your "major" components and manually pass into reusable components with few/no child components

Comment: We use the reducer in redux to handle this, so that we don't have to track the state through every single parent/child component

Comment: @pherris So, we mapStateToProps in our Router, our Router then passes to a HOC that checks the user credentials, then loads a child-component if they are authenticated. In the child-component, when I ask for `this.props.currentUser` in `componentDidMount`, it comes back with `{}`... so, should we just use mapStateToProps in our child-component?

Comment: @SterlingArcher so you mapStateToProps in the components that need state info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would pass the info from the store to the components that need it using `mapStateToProps` or a container.

Although this could be considered subjective, there is a real advantage of using containers instead of passing the props from Router: By properly using containers you can pass to components exactly the properties they depend on, nothing else, because any additional properties passed along through components that do not really affect how those components render or behave could be causing unnecessary rendering. Using `connect` you can "inject" the store information anywhere in the element tree, but using Router you have to pass it down from component to component.

Comment: So, by container, you mean, a data container that handles the API request and then loads the component when the API request returns? Would you also add a loading component to initially load or just null?

Comment: Or, do you mean the function mapStateToProps as the container?

Comment: The component that you create using connect with mapStateToProps is called a container